# get_bulk_payments - Method not found

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc

I'm trying to figure out how to process incoming payments and I'm stuck on the get_bulk_payments call...

Looking at the examples around, I was expecting to be able to type this:

`curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:18081/json_rpc -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"get_payments","params":{"payment_id":"4279257e0a20608e25dba8744949c9e1caff4fcdafc7d5362ecf14225f3d9030"}}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'`

And get details of payments to that payment id.

However, I'm getting this:

`{
  "error": {
    "code": -32601,
    "message": "Method not found"
  },
  "id": "0",
  "jsonrpc": "2.0"
}`

I'm running the Windows executable monerod.exe version v0.12.3.0

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

get_bulk_payments is not a monerod RPC, it's a wallet RPC. 
Run monero-wallet-rpc, and connect to its RPC port to use get_bulk_payments.

BTW, you wrote "get_payments" in the query JSON, not "get_bulk_payments".

Comment: Thanks - that made a difference.
Now I get an empty result "{}" - does the XMR address need to be in the wallet for this to work?

Comment: Clarify "does the XMR address need to be in the wallet for this to work".

Comment: When I request payments on the paymentId shown in the examples, I get an empty result set - even though there is a payment for that payment id (also shown in the examples)
Is this because the address the payment is for is not 'owned' or loaded in my wallet? In other words - to fetch payments for a payment id, do you also need to have the private keys for the address(es) in your wallet?

Comment: The wallet only stores the transactions from and to this wallet. It will not know about any other transaction.